# How to disable python asyncio fd storing? (Don't panic on same FD's)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Some library has a very huge logic, it looks like it does not close the connection properly and lefts `FD` in asyncio, but closing it in Linux.

My goal is to prevent panics when I am getting new connection FD.

**I am not going to fix somebody's else code or look for solving problem by properly closing the connection's fd**

Is there a way to close FD (only for asyncio) or disable `File descriptor N is used by transport` panics at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200946/runtimeerror-file-descriptor-8-is-used-by-transport

The problem description inside

Comment: In the place where the socket is obtained (before it's passed further to the library), replace `c1_socket = c1_writer.get_extra_info('socket')` with `import os, socket; c1_socket = socket.socket(fileno=os.dup(c1_writer.get_extra_info('socket').fileno())`